# Collision of files when doing the "svn up" command via ssh

Tags: svn, cakephp, ssh

I've been trying to update the server with the "svn up" command via ssh connection, and there was a notification saying that there is a collision of files - it was a jobs_controller file (cakephp).

So I've chosen the postpone option. But the update crashed the server so I reversed the changes by putting back again the old ones, but the job section on the site still doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the file on the server was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your site is in SVN and you check it out onto your server to run it? In which case it sounds like either you still have differences between the copy you are running and what is in SVN, or that what is in SVN doesn't work (ie. Is missing changes that you had locally before reverting). You can use:

```
svn -u status
```

to get a list of the files that are different between your local copy and the latest copy in SVN. Also use:

```
svn diff <filename>
```

To see differences between that file locally and the same file in SVN.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to have the same files on the server as they are on my local copy. I want the files to be back again as they are after I updated them.

Comment: Ah - are you trying to commit (save) your changes to your svn repository (server)? 'svn up' updates your local copy with any changes in SVN ( presumably made by other people). If you want to save changes back to the central repository, you want 'svn commit', eg: 'svn commit myfile.php'.

Comment: No - I've chosen the files to commit - then I've commited the changes. Then when I executed the svn up command some collision happened (with the file I didn't even change). Then I reversed the changes but the problem with this file stil exists.

Comment: This sounds more Cake PHP related issues than SVN which is outside my area of expertise. Sorry - hope you manage to find a solution.